# When a packet has multiple matches in a routing table what breaks the tie among rows?

Tags: security, networking

Just wondering what breaks the ties amount rows for a routing table.  Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: It would be more suited for you to post this on "information security" or "server fault" :)

Comment: @Boschko oh sorry wasn't sure what tags to put for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Administrative distance will be used by the routing table as the tie-breaker for candidate routes offered by the routing protocols.
when using the metric value to break a tie between entries in a routing table, the router selects the matching row with the highest or the lowest metric value, since the lower the value the more trusted the source of information is going to be.

That being said there are two parameters a router uses to break the tie;

1. Administrative Distance
2. Metric